# How to combine the information from 4 UITextfields into one UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uilabel

I have 4 text fields on one page and I want to get them to be shown on one label. My app asks the user their street, city, country, and postal code. For each input, there is a text field.

How would I get those textfields' information to be shown in a single label which is on another page?

I'm having the user put in their street, city, country, and postal code.

Then I'm having it be shown in a label: (123 street city, USA 12345).

Comment: What part of this process specifically do you need help with? What issue are you having?

Comment: I'm having trouble displaying the information from the text fields that the user inputted, into a label.

Comment: That's no more specific than what you put in your question. Do you know how to get the values of the text fields? Do you know how to create a string from multiple values? Do you know how to update a label's text? Which of those details do you need help with? [Edit] your question (don't post comments) with relevant details.

Answer (score 1):

We can just grab each of their texts and put them in a string using escapes. Here's a solution to your problem where the names of each object will most likely have to be changed:

```
textFieldStreet.text = "123 Street"
textFieldCity.text = "Townsville"
textFieldCountry.text = "USA"
textFieldPostal.text = "12345"

let finalText = "\(textFieldStreet.text!), \(textFieldCity.text!), \(textFieldCountry.text!) \(textFieldPostal.text!)"

outputLabel.text = finalText // This results in "123 Street, Townsville, USA 12345"
```

Just replace the names of each UITextField (textFieldStreet, etc.) with the names of your text fields, and replace the 'outputLabel' with the name of your output label!

Comment: The only problem with this is that it has fixed values to it. I want the user to enter these values

Comment: @SamiRehman the 'textFieldStreet.text' lines are just examples! If you want the user to enter those values, you must create a reference connection from your ViewController.swift to each UITextField in the Storyboard.

Then, you just use those UITextField names in place of 'textFieldCity' etc. Jlopesoares's answer will also provide a better option than force unwrapping (Thanks!), and my answer will provide you with a way to combine all of the entered text.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should have a reference for each TextField.

```
@IBOutlet var streetTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var cityTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var countryTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var postalCodeTextField: UITextField!
```

Secondly, since you want you user to write each information, you should protect you app avoiding force unwrap.

```
if let streetName = streetTextField.text {
   //if streetName gets value from the streetTextField it should add that info to the label
   addressLabel.text.append(streetName)
}
```

Repeat the process for each textField. 
There are many of options to implement what you need, however I believe this is one of the easiest ones.

Comment: Can I append this to a textfield instead of a label??  Thank you for your help :)))

Comment: Also I have a IBAction done button which contains this: @IBAction func done() {
    if let itemToEdit = itemToEdit {
      itemToEdit.text = postalCode.text!
      delegate?.itemDetailViewController(self, didFinishEditing: itemToEdit)
      } else {
      let item = ChecklistItem()
      item.text = postalCode.text!
      item.checked = false
      delegate?.itemDetailViewController(self, didFinishAdding: item)
    }
  }

Comment: So would I put this code into the done button or super.viewDidLoad

Comment: Yes you can append it to the textfield on it's `.text` attribute.

`Append` it's a function from the `String`class. Sou you can `append` things like `strings` or `characters` to another string.

The answer I suggest firstIy I would put on the done function.
When done button pressed, get the textfield values and put them on the label.

Comment: Would I delete the if and else statement in done function and replace it with the if statement you have stated??